Why is '(get …)' sometimes necessary in AppleScript?
I've been writing AppleScript for many years and one bit of reflexive syntax sprinkling I've learned to do when things aren't working is to add a (get …) around whatever I'm doing.
For instance:
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Alacritty"
        get item 1 of size of front window
    end tell
end tell

errors with:

System Events got an error: Can’t make item 1 of size of window 1 of application process "Alacritty" into type specifier.

but
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Alacritty"
        get item 1 of (get size of front window)
    end tell
end tell

results in the expected number.
Can someone explain why this is?

Based on @Mockman's answer, this has something to do with order of operations and what's handling each statement:
So an annotated execution might look something like:
tell application "System Events" -- Resolved at run time by AppleScript?
    tell application process "Alacritty" -- application process Alacritty resolved at run time by 'application "System Events", tell resolved by AppleScript?
        tell front window -- front window resolved by application process 'Alacritty', tell resolved by AppleScript?
            tell (get size) -- (get size) Resolved at run time by front window of application process Alacritty), tell resolved by AppleScript?
                get item 1 -- Resolved at run time by AppleSript (but why?)
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

Is there any mental model that helps explain why some components are resolved by AppleScript automatically while others require forcing one component like application process to resolve something beforehand? The Apple docs don't seem clear about how to think about it.

I think that it is because the application process "Alacritty" doesn't know what window sizes are but your command is directed (via Tell) at it. When you include the second get command inside the parentheses, then something else (either System Events or applescript itself) performs that function.
You can read what apple has to say about it here:
Commands Reference > get

However, an explicit get can be useful for forcing early evaluation of part of an object specifier. Consider:
tell application "Finder" to get word 1 of name of home

-- Finder got an error: Can’t get word 1 of name of folder "myname" of folder "Users" of startup disk.

This fails because Finder does not know about elements of text, such as words. AppleScript does, however, so the script has to make Finder get only the name of ... part:
tell application "Finder" to get word 1 of (get name of home)

--result: "myname"



Interesting. The part of this that doesn't follow for me is that the 'application process "Alacritty" doesn't know what window sizes are'. It has to know what window sizes are because it can return them with a get. tell application "System Events" to get item 1 of size of front window of application process "Google Chrome" fails but tell application "System Events" to get item 1 of (get size of front window of application process "Google Chrome") succeeds.
Regardless I'd never seen Apple's documentation about this so that's really helpful.

To be more concrete about why the examples in my prior comment are different, there's no tell there. I'm not telling the application process to do something. I'm just getting a property via application "System Events". So i don't think this explanation is quite right yet even though it's helpful.

I took the verbiage from the language guide. Another perspective is that it's an order of operations issue… 'get item 1 of size' doesn't mean anything whereas 'get item 1 of (size of front window) does.

Order of operations is very helpful. I still feel like I'm having trouble conceptualizing what's responsible for what at each level of the operation. Another bit from the language guide that seems helpful is that statements inside a tell block have implicit of application "Foo" at the end of them. I almost want a tree with what statement is handled by what and why.

Edited the question with an annotated resolution description that maybe helps get at where I'm confused.
